# error: control may reach end of non void function

Tags: c

I know this means that the function may reach the end without returning a value, but I'm not sure why.

```
bool bisearch(int value, int values[], int min, int max)
{
    if (max < min)
        return false;
    else
    {
        int midpoint = (max + min) / 2;
        if (value > values[midpoint])
            bisearch(value, values, midpoint + 1, max);
        else if (value < values[midpoint])
            bisearch(value, values, min, midpoint - 1);
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the marked lines are reached, no value is returned.

```
  bool bisearch(int value, int values[], int min, int max)
  {
      if (max < min)
          return false;
      else
      {
          int midpoint = (max + min) / 2;
          if (value > values[midpoint])
->            bisearch(value, values, midpoint + 1, max);
          else if (value < values[midpoint])
->            bisearch(value, values, min, midpoint - 1);
          else
              return true;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `bisearch` function returns a `bool` result.

The function calls itself twice -- but both times it discards the result.

Change both lines:

```
bsearch(value, ...);
```

to

```
return bsearch(value, ...);
```